# How to plot MFCC in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, speech-recognition, mfcc

Here is my code so far on extracting MFCC feature from an audio file (.WAV):

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

(rate,sig) = wav.read("AudioFile.wav")
mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)

print(mfcc_feat)
```

How can I plot the MFCC features to know what it looks like?

Answer (score 9):

This will plot the MFCC as colors, which is a more popular way

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mfcc_data= np.swapaxes(mfcc_data, 0 ,1)
cax = ax.imshow(mfcc_data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm, origin='lower')
ax.set_title('MFCC')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(rate,sig) = wav.read("AudioFile.wav")
mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)

print(mfcc_feat)
plt.plot(mfcc_feat)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers. Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Comment: what if I want to work with mp3/.mp4 files how will above code change?

Comment: This is not even the proper way of plotting mfcc features

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer did no defined mfcc_data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

(rate,sig) = wav.read("file.wav")
mfcc_feat = mfcc(sig,rate)

ig, ax = plt.subplots()
mfcc_data= np.swapaxes(mfcc_feat, 0 ,1)
cax = ax.imshow(mfcc_data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm, origin='lower', aspect='auto')
ax.set_title('MFCC')
#Showing mfcc_data
plt.show()
#Showing mfcc_feat
plt.plot(mfcc_feat)
plt.show()
```

[MFCC_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v08g6.png)
[MFCC_feat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDMSb.png)

Answer (score 2):

Initially I read the wav file using librosa and fed with inbuilt function

```
import librosa
audio_path='../.../../../combo.wav' #location
(xf, sr) = librosa.load(audio_path)    
mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=xf, sr=sr, n_mfcc=4)
librosa.display.specshow(mfccs, x_axis='time')
plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title('mfcc')
plt.show
```

I used librosa

Answer (score 0):

A more modern approach using `torchaudio` to read the audio and apply the `MFCC` transform.

```py
import torch
import torchaudio
import torchaudio.transforms as T
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

audio, fs = torchaudio.load("./audio.ogg")
mfcc_transform = T.MFCC(sample_rate=fs)

mfcc = mfcc_transform(audio)

plt.imshow(mfcc[0], interpolation="nearest", origin="lower", aspect="auto")
plt.colorbar()
```

Should produce something similar to:

[image]

More information in [torch docs](https://pytorch.org/audio/master/generated/torchaudio.transforms.MFCC.html).